# Android Studio: Connecting to Local SQLExpress Server

Tags: android, sql, android-studio

I am trying to connect to a local SQL server, but I'm getting exceptions. Code is below.

```
public class ConnectionClass {

    String ip =  "ipaddress\\servername";
    String db = "databasename";
    String un = "Username";
    String password = "Password";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        for (int tries = 0; tries < 3; tries++) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                ConnURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + ip + ";databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password=" + password + ";";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
                return conn;
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

When I don't include the port number (1433) in the connection string. It says there is a TCP issue.

When I do, it times out and says to check if UDP traffic is blocked by firewall on port 1434 (it isn't) and to make sure SQL Browser is running (it is).

Any ideas?